# Java - No such file or directory

Tags: java, macos

I have been trying to get this program to run a class file that is located in `/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe PCD/cache/Main.class.`

Yet every time I run the method below, It cannot find the file specified. I think that eclipse is looking for the file path above in the project folder. But the first command doesn't seem to work. Can Anyone help me? Is there another way to run the class file?

```
static Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

public static void Run() {

      try {
       Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
       String run = "/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe PCD/cache/";    
       String[] command = {"java -cp " + run, "java Main"};
       Process pr = rt.exec(command);

       BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

       String line=null;

       while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
       }

       int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
       System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

   } catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println(e.toString());
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `String[] command = {"java -cp " + run, " Main"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tries to run a mythical program `java -cp /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe PCD/cache/` with argument `java Main`.  `java Main` is an illegal name for a class too. Instead, have your command array be:

```
String[] command = {"java", "-cp", run, "Main"};
```

However, unless you have a `Main` class in the default package, simply add the `run` directory to your application's class path, and then *call* `Main.main()`, possibly playing games with standard input and output.  There is no need to start a second JVM. Or, figure out what `Main` does, and call the classes it calls.  Is there Javadoc for the Adobe code?

When the Ant task `<zip>` runs, Ant does not start a new VM or a command-line zip utility.  Instead, the task's class calls methods in `java.util.zip`. You should do something similar.